# If $A$ is generated as a $B$-algebra by $x_i$ and relations $r_j$, then $\Omega_{A/B}$ is generated over $A$ by $dx_i$ subject to $dr_j$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

This is Key Fact 21.2.3 in the November 2017 edition of Vakil's FOAG. I am trying to verify this fact but I am having trouble with one direction.

Here $\Omega_{A/B}$ is defined to be the free $A$-module generated by $da$ for $a \in A$, subject to the relations

1. $da + da' = d(a + a')$
2. $d(aa') = a \;da' + a'\;da$
3. $db = 0$ for $b \in B$.

Precisely, we want to show $\Omega_{A/B}$ is the $A$-module of $A$-linear combinations of $dx_i$, subject to (1)-(3) above *and* the relations $dr_j$ for all $j$.

Since $A$ is generated as a $B$-algebra by $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ subject to relations $\{r_{j}\}_{j \in J}$, we can view $r_j \in B[x_i]_{i \in I}$ as polynomials in $B$ so that we regard $A$ as the quotient $$A = B[x_i]_{i \in I}/(r_j)_{j \in J}.$$

So first off, $\Omega_{A/B}$ is generated by $dx_i$ as an $A$-module by the chain rule (or repeatedly applying the leibniz rule). Now we need to revise the relations. First of all, it is clear that these generators do indeed follow the relations (1)-(3) as well as $dr_j$, since $r_j = 0$ in $A$ to begin with.

Now, I am not sure how to proceed. I want to show $\Omega_{A/B}$ is *the* module generated by the generators and relations above. How can I show that the above relations are enough?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: I revised the question, correcting a mistake in my restatement of it.

For another attempt, we can denote $F$ the free $A$-module generated by $da$ for $a \in A$, and take $R \subseteq F$ to be the submodule generated by those relations (1)-(3). Then, we define $\Omega_{A/B}$ to be the cokernel $$0 \to R \to F \to \Omega_{A/B} \to 0.$$

Let us denote $M$ to be the module generated by $dx_i$ for $i \in I$, subject to (1)-(3) above as well as $dr_j$ for $j \in J$. We attempt to fit $M$ in the above exact sequence. For each $a \in A$, we can write $da$ as an $A$-linear combination of $dx_j$. This yields a function $\{da\:|\;a \in A\} \to M$, yielding an $A$-linear map $F \to M$. It is easy to see that this map is surjective. Now we just need to show that the kernel of this map is $R$.

Comment: One way to do this is to use the conormal sequence: if $C = B[x_i]_{i\in I}$ and $J$ is the kernel of the projection $C\to A,$ then there is an exact sequence
$$
J/J^2\xrightarrow{\delta} A\otimes_C\Omega_{C/B}\to \Omega_{A/B}\to 0.
$$
You can compute that $\Omega_{C/B}\cong \bigoplus_{i\in I} Cdx_i,$ so $A\otimes_C\Omega_{C/B}\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I} Adx_i.$ Then, it follows that $\Omega_{A/B}\cong\bigoplus_{i\in I} Adx_i/\operatorname{Im}\delta,$ so all that remains is to show that $\operatorname{Im}\delta$ is the module generated by the relations.

Comment: Perhaps I should just do this. Vakil has this exercise before the conormal sequence so I was hoping it wouldn't be necessary. Thank you. The way you present it there seems to make it clearer.

Comment: @Stahl Indeed, after learning about the conormal exact sequence, this is a much easier way to do this. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome! I suggest you write an answer to your own question and accept it, to help others see what you've learned and to remove the question from the list of questions with no accepted answer. Of course, writing what you've learned is a great way to better understand it yourself as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = B[x_i]_{i \in I}/(r_j)_{j \in J}$. We would like to compute $\Omega_{A/B}$ using the conormal sequence. Let $I = (r_j)_{j \in J}$ be the ideal in $B[x_i]_{i \in I}$. There we recall the conormal exact sequence of $A$-modules$$I/I^2 \stackrel{\delta}\to A \otimes_B \Omega_{B[x_i]/B} \to \Omega_{A/B} \to 0.$$ Now we observe that $\Omega_{B[x_i]/B} = \bigoplus_{i \in I} Bdx_i$ canoncially so that the middle term of the above exact sequence becomes $A \otimes_B \bigoplus_{i \in I} Bdx_i = \bigoplus_{i \in I} Adx_i$. Hence, we just need to show that the image of $\delta$ is generated by $dr_i$. This is easy, though, since $\delta([f]) = 1 \otimes df$ by definition. This the guarantees that since $I/I^2$ is generated by $[r_i]$, we have that that the image of $\delta$ is generated by $\delta([r_i]) = 1 \otimes dr_i \sim dr_i$ where the $\sim$ is the identification $A \otimes_B \bigoplus_{i \in I} Bdx_i = \bigoplus_{i \in I} Adx_i$.

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "This is Key Fact 21.2.3 in the November 2017 edition of Vakil's FOAG. I am trying to verify this fact but I am having trouble with one direction.
Here $\Omega_{A/B}$ is defined to be the free $A$-module generated by $da$ for $a \in A$, subject to the relations

1. $da + da' = d(a + a')$
2. $d(aa') = a \;da' + a'\;da$
3. $db = 0$ for $b \in B$.

Precisely, we want to show $\Omega_{A/B}$ is the $A$-module of $A$-linear combinations of $dx_i$, subject to (1)-(3) above *and* the relations $dr_j$ for all $j$."

**Answer:** When you define $\Omega:=\Omega^1_{A/B}$ as in 1-3 it is immediate that $\Omega$ is generated by $\overline{dx}$ for $x\in A$.

**Note:** Here you should "overline" the $dx$ to make clear to the reader you are speaking about equivalence classes. Take any element $\omega \in\Omega$. Since

$$\Omega:=\oplus_{x\in A}Adx/U,$$

where $U$ is the submodule generated by the elements in $1-3$ in your question, it follows (by definition) that there is a finite set of elements $a_i,x_i \in A$
with $\omega=\overline{\sum_i a_idx_i}= \sum_i a_i\overline{dx_i}$. This is beacuse the direct sum $\oplus_{x\in A}Adx$ is the set of finite sums $\sum_{i=1}^k a_idx_i$ for $a_i,x_i \in A$. Hence $\Omega$ is generated by the elements $\overline{dx}$ as left $A$-module for varying $x\in A$.